# Sensory wake word error in raspberry pi while making alexa

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

```
cloning into 'alexa-rpi'
fatal: remote error:
repository not found
```

I'm getting this error from so many days

this is the command I used :-

```
git clone git://github.com/Sensory/alexa-rpi.git
```

I searched in GitHub and tried but it is showing license is expired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to:

https://github.com/alexa/avs-device-sdk/issues/1980

https://github.com/alexa/avs-device-sdk/issues/1976

Amazon is seemingly looking at the issue, but as Sensory has made a business decision to remove the repository, it might not be easy to come up with a satisfactory solution.

Kitt.AI is easily triggered by sounds/words other than the wake word, I find it very annoying to say the least...

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a work around. Sensor Wakeword Engine is no longer available on their Github: https://github.com/Sensory. However, there are some other WakeWord Engines available: https://github.com/Kitt-AI/snowboy. For more: https://medium.com/@alirezakenarsarianhari/yet-another-wake-word-detection-engine-a2486d36d8d4

For help with patching the AVS-SampleApp I found this helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wiLEr6TeE58